# Web page is cut off in IE6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

I have a site at http://www.dellsvet.com/ which is being affected by a bug in IE6. The page will only show what will fit in the viewport, and you're unable to scroll down in IE6. I thought that I was dealing with the unscrollable content bug detailed here: http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/unscrollable.html -- but it's not a match as far as I can find. I've been tinkering with this for a while with no result.

Does anyone have any insight on this bug? I've got a feeling this is something simple staring me in the eye, but I'm missing it.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this issue only affect IE6 and no other browsers?

Comment: You know that IE6 is good enough for the national museum?

Comment: @Thew: IE6 fixing in 2011: It's either for "commercial purposes", or to appease the insatiable perfectionist streak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider not caring about IE6 because it's becoming more and more rare. Nevertheless, you asked a question, so I'm going to answer it.

Simply remove `position: relative` and `z-index: 1` from `#container`.

Doing that fixes IE6, and I did not notice any differences in IE7/IE8 or Firefox.

---

**Bonus, because I'm nice:**

To fix the menu buttons, add this to your CSS:

```
.ie6 #nav li a { zoom: 1; display: inline }
```

Thanks to your use of [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/), you have that nice easy way to feed CSS to IE6.

To get (*the drop downs*) `ul#nav li:hover ul` working in IE6, you can use [Whatever:hover](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html).

Other than the above issues, that page looks fine to me in IE6.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I don't normally support IE6, but it was called for on this particular site.